# Javascript split() on a time string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, split

I have a string that can be in the following formats (the numbers are examples):

```
2h34m2s
23m6s
7h8s
4h2m
3h
2m
2s
```

I was originally going to just use `split()` with a regex to match `h`, `m` and `s`. However, that would fail if only some metrics were present (if its of the form `2m3s`, then I would need a way to know that the first entry in the array represents minutes and not hours).

I assume the proper solution would involve regex of some sort, but it current escapes me. Any ideas for a clean and efficient solution?

edit:

(I'd like to accept any number of digits, so I'm not using `{1,2}` in the regex.

```
var timeString = $('#interval').val();
var hours = timeString.match('/\d+(?=h)/')[0];     // 2h4m8s
var minutes = timeString.match('/\d+(?=m)/')[0];
var seconds = timeString.match('/\d+(?=s)/')[0];
console.log('hours: ' + hours);
console.log('minutes: ' + minutes);
console.log('seconds: ' + seconds);
```

The console is giving `null` for the values.

Comment: You can use a regex with lookaheads here.

Comment: @Christoph, thanks for the hint, I've never come across those before but its never too late to learn.

Comment: I'm withmy mobile, but I added a short answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex with positive lookaheads here:

```
/\d{1,2}(?=h)/
```

Would match hours: one or two digits when followed by the letter `h`. Analogous for `m` and `s`.

Comment: `"12h34m3s".match(/\d{1,2}(?=h)/)` works for me giving the hours as result. Maybe you are not getting the string back from your DOM element in the first place?

Comment: Ah, right. I overlooked that. Regex are literals, you never need to quote them.

Comment: Regex literals are literals. You have to put quotes around them when using the `RegExp` constructor though. The `/ /` signifies it's a literal. (just being nit-picky)

Comment: Just nitpicking: literals ar never quoted. What you are quoting in the RegExp Constructor is an ordinary string;) But you are right, you can either use a regex as string and quote it or use the literal form `//`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following regular expressions:

`\d+(?=m)` for minutes,

`\d+(?=h)` for hours, and

`\d+(?=s)` for seconds.

You should probably do a case-insensitive match.

Comment: @Christoph : I didn't do that! In fact, I've _never_ cast a downvote on SO. I just reached the required reputation today.

Comment: Sorry for accusing, I guess it was some other guy here, who votes us both down.

Comment: @Christoph : I forgive you. Good faith shown by upvote on your answer :)

Answer (score 2):

```
var string = "23h4m"
var regexp = /(\d+h)?(\d+m)?(\d+s)?/;
var result = string.match(regexp) // gives you ["23h4m", "23h", "4m", undefined]
```

You may access the result with `result[1]` for the hours, `result[2]` for minutes, and `result[3]` for seconds. The values are undefined, if not given.

Comment: The simplest solution for sure.

Answer (score 1):

```
//match any digits and include the letters

var rx=/((\d+)(h|m|s))/g;    

//test:
var str1='2h34m2s',str2='23m6s';

str1+'=\n\t'+str1.match(rx).join(':\n\t')+'\n'+
str2+'=\n\t'+str2.match(rx).join(':\n\t')
//returns

2h34m2s=
    2h:
    34m:
    2s
23m6s=
    23m:
    6s
```